# Changing null strings to string.Empty using ValueInjecter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, valueinjecter

I'm using ValueInjecter to flatten/unflatten view models into domain objects created by Entity Framework (4.3.1) model-first.  All of my `VARCHAR` columns in my database are `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` (personal preference, no desire to open up a holy war here).  On post, the view model comes back with any string property that has no value as null, so when I attempt to inject it back into my domain model class, EF barks at me for attempting to set a property with `IsNullable=false` to null.  Example (over-simple):

```
public class ThingViewModel
{
    public int ThingId{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class Thing
{
    public global::System.Int32 ThingId
    {
        //omitted for brevity
    }

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Name
    {
        //omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Then, my controller post looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ThingViewModel thing)
{
    var dbThing = _thingRepo.GetThing(thing.ThingId);
    //if thing.Name is null, this bombs
    dbThing.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(thing);
    _thingRepo.Save();
    return View(thing);
}
```

I'm using `UnflatLoopValueInjection` because I have nested types in the actual domain version of `Thing`.  I attempted to write a custom `ConventionInjection` to convert null strings to `string.Empty`, but it appears that `UnflatLoopValueInjection` switches it back to null.  Is there a way I can get ValueInjecter not to do this?

Comment: Model-First or Code-First? If Model-First or DB-First, are you using a custom T4? If so or you are using Code-First, then you could add a null check into the properties' setters.

Comment: @DannyVarod model-first, as stated in the question, not using a custom T4.  I attempted to reflect the attributes of the `TargetProp` and didn't get very far with that.

Comment: some people confuse the two. If you are using the default generator T4s, then your entity should have a base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuts, I just figured it out with help from the [wiki](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=unflattening&referringTitle=Documentation).  The solution appears to be to extend `UnflatLoopValueInjection`:

```
public class NullStringUnflatLoopValueInjection : UnflatLoopValueInjection<string, string>
{
    protected override string SetValue(string sourceValue)
    {
        return sourceValue ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```